# Is all redis cluster master nodes data same?

Tags: java, caching, redis, spring-data-redis

For example, I have A, B, C master nodes and A1, B1, C1 slave nodes in redis cluster.
I know A would sync data to A1, as well as B and C.

So, are there the same data in A, B, C master nodes?

Comment: If you're talking about [Redis Cluster](https://redis.io/documentation#redis-cluster), these 3 master nodes have different data set.

Comment: Thanks. If I have A, B, C, D master nodes and A1, B1, C1, D1 slave nodes with redis cluster, and I shutdown D and D1. I get the `Failed to refresh slots cache` error. How can I refresh slot?

Comment: All right, I find how to fix this error. Running `redis-cli --cluster fix host:port` command to fix it.